# Android solution to save multiple photos in a single file: .mpo

Tags: java, android, c, image-processing, jpeg

I am developing an Android application where I need to save multiple photos in a single file. I want to use the multiple picture format .mpo. I checked in Android documentation as well as in OpenCV (I use OpenCV for image processing) but did not found a way to save multiple JPEG pictures in a single file (I found only ways to extract images from mpo file).
 Such file save format is useful to store stereo photo (store left & right), bracketing, HDR, ... 
 Do you know a way to perform this (specific function or parameters? Bitmap.CompressFormat does not include mpo), or a sample java or c program to combine multiple JPEG files in a single MPO?
 Thanks a lot.

Comment: I never got feedback on this question. Is there any way to store multiple images in a single file with other libraries? Thanks.